# A Simple Happy Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I mock my stature and my girth
>   I am a frantic poet at birth
>   Upend me now and bleed me dry
>   Scalding colored tears I'll cry

The answer is a single English word. Please also identify the obscure song reference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like a

> Teapot 
>  Because of the song "I'm a little teapot" 
>  
>  I mock my stature and my girth - "Stout and short" 
>  I am a frantic poet at birth - Anagram of "poet at" 
>  Upend me now and bleed me dry - "Tip me over and pour me out" 
>  Scalding colored tears I'll cry - Hot tea will flow out

Comment: My one regret is that I couldn't include the bit about anger issues.

Comment: @HughMeyers Is that song actually considered "obscure"? Or did you mean it was "obscured"?

Comment: @ChrisSunami It was half tongue in cheek and half the latter.

Comment: Frantic poet might also refer to a teapot whistling when it boils.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found the song yet.

However, the thing you are refering to is

> a pen or stift

I mock my stature and my girth

> the form or shape of a pen doesn't change the way you use it

I am a frantic poet at birth

> from the moment it is finished, you can write with it

Upend me now and bleed me dry

> you have to upend a pen to write with it and you use the ink to write

Scalding colored tears I'll cry

> the ink can have many different colors

Comment: Es ist nicht ein Stift. Ist das ein Wort auf Englisch? I'm afraid pen isn't the answer but I like your reasoning. Pen doesn't fit with "scalding" tears and there is a better fit for the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the word?

> waterfall

I mock my stature and my girth

> the start of the river

I am a frantic poet at birth

> the sound of the river

Upend me now and bleed me dry

> when the river creates another small river

Scalding colored tears I'll cry

> when the river turns into the waterfall

Comment: That's a beautiful image. Thanks for answering and welcome to puzzling.stackexchange. This question already has an accepted answer. It is the one above with the green check mark. Keep puzzling and good luck!